# Dynamic textbox creation based on textbox input

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

If I give semicolon as input means I have to create a textbox in jQuery. I tried this code and it flows correctly but it didn't show me the result.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("#hellotxt").on('keyup', function (event){
            if (event.keyCode == 59)
            {
                var txt = $("#hellotxt").val();
                var valueArray = txt.split(';');
                var valueSortArray = valueArray.sort();
                for (var i = 0; i < valueSortArray.length - 1; i++) {
                    alert("friends");
                    addbox();
                }
            }
        });
});
```

addbox code is here

```
 function addbox() {
        var table = $(this).closest('table');
        if (table.find('input:text').length >= 0) {
            table.append('<tr> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /></td> <td><input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td></tr>');
        }
    }
```

My ASp.Net Markup is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="hellotxt" runat="server" placeholder="hi;ji;ki;li;">    </asp:TextBox>
   <table border="0" cellspacing="2">   
<tr>        
    <td>
        <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
        <input type="button" id="del" value="Del" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "If I give semicolon as input means I have to create a textbox in jQuery"? It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: my input to textbox is ";" @good4m

Comment: So you need dynamic textboxes if user gives input as ";". Why are you complicating this? Is it not possible to give a button to add a new text box?

Comment: ya i like to add it in dynamic..i need it in textbox event not in button click na..@SelvaTS..it works in button click i tried already

Comment: @SelvasudarDuraipandian  i have updated my answer with fiddle example . pls check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will get answer from this code..please you all guys check it out

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  //page load
    $("#hellotxt").on('keypress', function (event) {
        console.log(event.which)
        if (event.which == 59 || event.which == 186) {
            var txt = $("#hellotxt").val();
            var valueArray = txt.split(';');
            var valueSortArray = valueArray.sort();
            for (var i = 0; i < valueSortArray.length - 1; i++) {
                addbox.call(this, valueSortArray);
            }
        }
    });

 function addbox(valueSortArray) {
 var table = $(this).next('table').find("tbody");
 table.find(".dyn").remove()
 $.each(valueSortArray, function (i, v) {
 console.log(i,v)
 if (v)
     table.append('<tr class="dyn"><td><input type="text"  value="' + v + '" /></td></tr> ');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

check below code keycode for ';' is 186 . check working example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw424ht5/)

```
 $("#hellotxt").on('keyup', function (event){

 if (event.keyCode == 186)
    {
        var OBJ = $(this);
        var txt = $("#hellotxt").val();
        var valueArray = txt.split(';');
        var valueSortArray = valueArray.sort();
        for (var i = 0; i < valueSortArray.length - 1; i++) {
            addbox(OBJ);
        }
    }
});
```

pass $(this)(hellotxt object) as argument in function

```
function addbox( OBJ ) {
   var table = OBJ.next('table');

   if (table.find('input').length >= 0) {
    table.append('<tr> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /></td> <td><input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td></tr>');
  }
}
```

Comment: go through my answer please @jquery i upvoted you for answering me

Comment: yes just check .. see my answer its simple solution of your question .  great you got your answer :) .